# How do I prove this product by induction?

Tags: induction

$$n \in \mathbb{N} $$ $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^k =  \frac{n^n}{n!}$$

How do I prove this by induction?

I tried something like this:

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{1}\right)^1  
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \times \dots \times 
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n 
=  \frac{n^n}{n!} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$

And then tried to rearrange the right side until:

$$ \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $$

But that didn't work. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially did it:
$$\frac{n^n}{n!}(1+\frac1n)^n=\frac{n^n}{n!}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=
\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}\frac{n+1}{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: Aaaah brilliant! Thanks for the help! Now I get it